# Determine if a method call is executing on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

So recently I was asked this an interview:

> Suppose you have been given a third party black box java library, you are calling a method from that library. How would you determine if that method call is executing on multiple threads?

I mentioned that I can :

- Get a thread dump and find out
- Run a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) and check from there
- check using [Thread.currentThread()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread())[.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getName())

But they didn't seem satisfied with the answers. What would be the proper way of answering this?

Comment: Who isn't satisfied with your answers?

Comment: People who invite for interviews so interviewee will tell them how to solve problem interviewer has, or people who are looking for very specific answer the thought about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the function [`Thread.activeCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()) that gives you the amount of currently active threads.

You could store the returned value before calling the third party method and compare that to the returned value while it's running.

You have to make sure not to create/terminate threads outside the method while it's running, otherwise the result would be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer would be to look at the source code.  I know he said "black box", but there ain't no such thing where code is involved.  It's easy if I got both a library.jar and library-sources.jar, but even if all I have is the library.jar, then just use a decompiler on it.  That moves the problem from "evidence of multithreading" to "multithreading confirmed".

The second best way would be to RTFM.  Is it documented as using threads and/or being thread-safe?  Well then, there ya go.  But as we all know, documentation is always lacking, so I don't have a lot of hope here.  Still, sometimes you get lucky.

Then... I would go where you went with the profiles and thread-dumps etc.

That said, it's a pretty poor question.  As an **operational** question, who cares if a library is multithreaded as long as it executes correctly and it performs expeditiously.  It's not your code, so if it fails (accuracy, or performance), you don't care why - go tell whoever owns it to fix it.

As an **interview** question, you're evaluating problem-solving skills.  Does the applicant approach it in different ways.  The more ways to attack the problem, the more senior a person you are likely dealing with - source code inspection, decompilation, profiles, thread dumps, log messages, documentation, etc, etc.  The most senior folks will give you the "who cares, if it's a black box, it's not my problem.  Tell someone else to fix it and meet my SLA."  :)   If you don't have a clue what skillset(s) the interviewer was looking for, then the problem may be the interviewer.  Junior interviewers often assume there is only one answer (or only one correct answer), when in fact multiples exist - some better than others, but depends on the situation.  If you've already given your answer and still get the 'frowny face', (politely) ask them what they were looking for.  You'll actually learn *A LOT* with this question.  Some will pull the 'i'm not telling, it's my interview' (command-driven organization where collaboration is not sought).  Some will try and guide you toward the right answer, or tell you the question-within-a-question, which gives you a chance to recover.

Answer (score 1):

StackWalker and Thread.getStacktrace can be used to list all **currently** active methods, something like this should do the job, more or less:

```
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : thread.getStackTrace()) {
        stackTraceElement.getClassName()
        stackTraceElement.getMethodName();
    }
}
```

Stacktraces around all threads change very quickly, so it's not super reliable method, but might be what they were looking for.